# Not able to get control in readObject while reading objects from DB using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, serialization

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student implements serializable{

@Column(name="sid") 
private int sid;
@Column(name="name") 
private String name;
@Column(name="addressXml") 
private String addressXml;

@Transient
private Address addressObj;


}
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ---Not getting control here
        in.defaultReadObject();

        addressXml =(String)in.readObject();
        addressObj =(Address) xstream.fromXML(addressXml);

}
```

I have a following situation in which while doing `getResultList` I need control in `readObject` so that I can convert `addressXml` to `addressObj` and set the transient variable .

```
List<Student> list = query.getResultList();
```

But i am not getting control in `readyObject`.

Note: `Student` object already persist in db and I am using Hibernate JPA implementation to retrieve `Student` objects.

Could you guys help me to understand what exactly i am missing here ?

Comment: and why do you think "readObject" should be called? somebody serializing an object?

Comment: Cause Student object already persist in DB hence while reading them i am kind of dserializing them right ? Do you know how this problem can be approached ?

Comment: if they are in the db and being read from the DB there is no "de-serialization" happening ... unless you stored the object in a BLOB!

Comment: Note that addressXml is stored are CLOB in DB. Is there any workaround for to handle this situation so that I shall get object out of xml on the go ?

Comment: addressXml is a STRING. That will not call readObject of Student! The only way readObject of Student is called is if you serialised Student. You can use JPA event handlers such as PostLoad to see the value

Comment: I am working on web application where query.getResultList() returns 10/20/50 records as per user input and i want the transient field to be populated before it returns List<Student> list looks PostLoad listener needs an event to occur!

Comment: Thanks you so much  PostLoad solved my problem ! Below is the reference link for the same  [link] (http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/EntityListenerPostLoad.htm)

Comment: glad it works. I added as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Java serialisation process in use when pulling an object back from the DB, unless you store an Entity as serialized. If you just want to get a handle on a FIELD when pulled back from the DB then you can make use of the JPA PostLoad event listener.